# Keep all `thead th` on sticky position with data table

Tags: html, css

In my data table requirement, I need to keep 2 `thead` with table. I require to keep both of them in stick approach. But when scrolls only the last `thead's tr` alone stick to top. but the first element is getting hides.

any one help me to sort this issue. since the top position are mixing with both it's happens. but i do not know the height of each of them, since the values added through dynamic.

CSS :

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table{
  width: 100%;;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
}

thead{
  overflow-y: auto;
}

thead tr th{
  background-color: yellow;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

[Live Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KMLAvUX2PgTA7FH9?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just by single `thead`
If you insist on using two `thead`, you should be aware that use different class for each `thead` and the second one should have suitable value for top property

This example contains two `thead` first has `span` and `input` and the second one has just an `input` like your example and all stick on top correctly

```css
.container{
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    table{
      width: 100%;;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      position: relative;
    }

    thead{
      text-align:left;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0; top: 0;
    }
   .secondth{
      text-align:left;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0; 
      top: 42px;
    }
    thead tr th{
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    thead tr th span{
    display:block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
        <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <span>One</span>
                  <input type="text" value="search" />
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span>Two</span>
                  <input type="text" value="search" />
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span>Thr</span>
                  <input type="text" value="search" />
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead class="secondth">
          <tr>
            <th><input type="text" value="search" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" value="search" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" value="search" /></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
                <td>comment1</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the solution not working with Chrome browser. which is the most require in business

Comment: I just have tested with Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131, it works correctly!.

Comment: mine is version "89.0.4389.90" - will check on it. If possible, if you have any solution to come up with all versions I am welcome!!

Comment: I tested on Firefox and Edge too and see no problem, would you please send a pic of the problem.

Comment: Problem with chrome down version, example the version one I use. or less than that.